do.call() function generates 2 different length results
here is "final.csv"
# rm(list = ls())
dta <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JoshXie0809/cchat_wife_election_1/main/final.csv")
library(stringi)
library(parallel)
split(dta$content, dta$nameid) |> 
    lapply( function(x) stri_extract(x[1], regex = "(@喜多郁代|@早坂愛)") ) -> res

res1 <- do.call(c, res)
res2 <- do.call(rbind, res)

length(res)
# [1] 5713
length(res1)
# [1] 5712
nrow(res2)
# [1] 5713

which(!names(res) %in% names(res1))
# > which(!names(res) %in% names(res1))
# [1] 4100
which(!names(res) %in% rownames(res2))
# integer(0)

res[4100]
# $recursive
# [1] "@早坂愛"

res                             has 5713
but using do.call(c, res)     has 5712
and       do.call(rbind, res) has 5713
enter image description here
I want to ask,
why I get 2 different length?
I think 4100 data does not have any problem

For the record, do.call doesn't generate any length, it is the what= function argument that is generating different lengths. Also, please NEVER include rm(list=ls()) in code in a question. There are some users that will mistakenly try your code and lose anything/everything. It's not necessary. If you want to communicate that you are starting with an empty environment, then perhaps include it commented-out, which I will do now.

@r2evans He's probably an immigrant from MATLAB, where generations of idiots have told their students to start every macro with clear all   :-(

@CarlWitthoft In another question/chat, I'm trying to find out what tutorial/howto actually recommends as.data.frame(cbind(..)), a practice that is never (afaict) warranted or advantageous. My point is that whatever tutorial/teacher is actually recommending it is demonstrably not proficient in R, though I admit I hadn't quite gotten to the word "idiot". (I hope no MATLAB user takes offense, I'm interpreting "generations of idiots" to be uninformed promulgation of bad techniques. :-)

It can be informative to compare the names between the two objects:
setdiff(names(res1), rownames(res2))
# character(0)
setdiff(rownames(res2), names(res1))
# [1] "recursive"

So one of your dataset has a name "recursive". Since you're calling do.call(c, res), let's look at ?c:
Description:

     This is a generic function which combines its arguments.

     The default method combines its arguments to form a vector.  All
     arguments are coerced to a common type which is the type of the
     returned value, and all attributes except names are removed.

Usage:

     ## S3 Generic function
     c(...)
     
     ## Default S3 method:
     c(..., recursive = FALSE, use.names = TRUE)

Notice the recursive = FALSE?
Okay, what's happening: when you use do.call, typically:

all named arguments in args= are applied to the same-named arguments in the what= function
all remaining arguments in args= are applied either to the pre-... named and yet-unused arguments in the function, or they are applied to the ... ellipses, if the function is defined with it

In this case, recursive= is both a name in your dataset and a named argument of c(..), so it is applied there. Unfortunately, c(.) doesn't complain that recursive="@早坂愛" is not logical. (To me, that's a bug, it should loudly complain. But that's just me.)
Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to provide named arguments to c where one of those names is recursive=, without that argument being interpreted incorrectly. For do.call(c, ..), I think you're stuck ...
Some thoughts:

do.call(c, res) (ignoring the lost element) is really doing nothing here, it's returning a named-list with the same names and same values. We can do res1 <- c(res), though really identical(res, c(res)) is true so ... we're just wasting time typing it out like that. If your res is actually a nested-list (list of lists?), it likely does work there.
On that note, we can do res1 <- do.call(c, list(res)) and get all 5713 elements including "recursive". In this case, it's akin to calling c(list(res)) which is (still?) doing very little, but at least you can use it programmatically. That step is specific to c(), though, so not something that can be used generically.

If you want to do this "generically", where the function used in do.call is not necessarily known a priori, then you can do a quick hack to work around it. (Odd that we cannot use formals(c) to find the names it will choke on ...)
need_to_hide <- intersect(names(res), c("recursive", "use.names"))
need_to_hide
# [1] "recursive"
names(res) <- paste0(ifelse(names(res) %in% need_to_hide, "_", ""), names(res))
grep("recur", names(res1), value=TRUE)
# [1] "_recursive"
names(res1) <- sub("^_", "", names(res1))
grep("recur", names(res1), value=TRUE)
# [1] "recursive"

While not perfectly elegant, it's one way to generically work around R's c function and "hidden" arguments that defy using do.call they way you intended.

I'm actually making a quick edit, not that is comes up with many better alternatives, but ... anyway, you'll see an edit soon :-)

@Josh a small edit, glad it helped (at least a little)
